# apache tiles ordering problem

Tags: java, spring-mvc, tiles

I have a problem with the order of rendering tiles. The menu gets rendered first and then the body of our webpage gets rendered. Each tile has it`s own controller that handles everything that tile needs to do. There are two forms. One in the menu and one in the body. Each one changes something in the menu and in the body. The problem is that if a form in the body changes something the menu gets rendered first and then the body controller handles form things and puts data to session, but menu is already done and the session was empty.

I can't turn body and menu around becaouse there are other forms that work the other way around. How to deal with this problem? I do want every tile to have it's own controller that deals with everything that tile does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution. First controller called is now the searchController that does the search and then goes to a tiles definition that builds the webpage. So searchController gets called twice. Second time it only returns view location.